# welcome page via wireless internet

Tags: networking, router, internet, wifi, iphone

i want to make welcome page if users are surfing via my wirelesss connection

for example

user come to my resturant with his iphone
and search for wireless networkrs
the user see the resturant wireless and connect to it.

when the user open the browser the first page he will see is 
my restuarnt web site

how can i accomplish it ?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Well you have to configure the router to redirect user on first request to your "welcome screen".
This welcome screen ought to be a html document either on local server or some www page on a server/hosting you own.

That's that ;]
For any precise information you would probably have to provide name of your router and what kind of software you have on it...
Without that its hard to give any specific solution.

Comment: my router model is: edimax br-6204wg

i dont know how to get the software..
mybe this ?
Hardware Version   Rev. A
Boot Code Version   1.0
Runtime Code Version   1.51

Comment: I recomend going to community groups of that particular router.
They might give you better info...!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, most hotspot (wireless) providers accomplish this via WPAD. I think that's the gist of what Marek is suggesting, but your wireless AP\Router needs to support it.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Autodiscovery_Protocol