# Temporarily redirect all network traffic to website

Tags: linux, bind, redirect

*I've got very little experience with nameservers and really need some guidance on this project - all help is appreciated!*

I've started a project where I'm going to set up a **wireless network** similar to what we are used to from **hotels and airports** where you connect to the internet and then have to **open a browser** to accept the terms and conditions before you get connected to the Internet.

In my project, I want to redirect all of the user's traffic to a specific local website, say "**mycompanywifi.com**", until they've clicked a **"go online"-button**. However, the page that users are redirected to must be usable. In example: **mycompanywifi.com/news** should **not be redirected** to mycompanywifi.com, if that makes any sense.

**What I know:**

- Linux
- set up nameserver with bind9 (done once some time ago)
- set up webservers (LAMP)
- PHP, HTML, CSS and JavaScript

**What I have:**

- A Raspberry PI
- A router with wich I can change DNS servers

**My idea:**

My initial idea was to set up a nameserver with bind9 on the Raspberry to which all the Internet traffic should be redirected to. I think I would be able to do that, but the problem is that I don't know how, or if it's even possible, to stop redirecting after the button click. Any ideas?

---

Similiar questions:

- [Redirect all traffic on my network to a welcome page](https://serverfault.com/questions/659699/redirect-all-traffic-on-my-network-to-a-welcome-page)
- [welcome page via wireless internet](https://serverfault.com/questions/90030/welcome-page-via-wireless-internet?rq=1)

Comment: The technology is called a captive portal and the wikipedia already explains a couple of techniques: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal

Comment: Until you _do_ have experience, you'd probably do better to use an off-the-shelf captive portal.